# Confusing JavaScript libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, typescript, mobile-application

I am building my first mobile app with HTML5/Javascript/CSS. I am feeling overwhelmed by number of JavaScript libraries out there. In short time that I spent; I came across JsRender, nodeJS, backbonejs, knockoutjs, TypeScript, CoffeeScript, Jquery... Is there a generally accepted as a "Best Practice" document for building mobile apps? So that I don't have to read about each of these libraries and figure out what I should and shouldn't use.

I guess this might not qualify as a specific enough question, but I couldn't find better forum to ask.

Comment: If you just want to make some mobile app, go with http://jquerymobile.com/ or http://www.sencha.com/products/touch
PS: node is not for frontend, but for backend application.

Comment: thanks, for the quick replay. I guess I should have been more specific that I am building a data intense app, involving mashup between couple of APIs + user data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the JS libraries that you mention have each a different purpose.

- JsRender is for jQuery templating
- nodeJS is a JavaScript **server**
- Backbone is a JS library for applications client side built following the **MVC** pattern
- Knockout is a JS library for applications client side built following the **MVVM** pattern
- TypeScript and CoffeeScript are JS **precompilers** (allowing you to write code "easier", which compiles to JS)

I don't think there is any "best practice" here, since they all serve a different purpose. Learn their differences, pick one and go with it.

If you want to build a mobile app, I would suggest [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) (but once again, that's a personal favorite). Others include [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch), [Kendo UI Mobile](http://www.kendoui.com/mobile.aspx), [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/), ...

Comment: thanks, for the quick replay. I guess I should have been more specific that I am building a data intense app, involving mashup between couple of APIs + user data.

Comment: @socialMatrix: Doesn't change the answer.

Comment: @socialMatrix it sounds like you might be compiling a list of technology before you have come across a problem. Start writing the app and when you find a problem that is best solved by a framework - look for one that does what you need.